# how to pronounce I'm

Tags: abbreviations

**TL;DR
you can hear very frequently: "am this" "am that", is this wrong?**

Very simple query about how to pronounce a basic English abbreviation:

I'm

should this sound as if the "I" was not even there (like "am") or - as I always thought it was - a very fast "Im" where is the central "a" that disappear?

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?  There are phonemic transcriptions available as well as the ability to click a button and hear it spoken.  Of course, in casual speech some speakers might reduce it further beyond the pronunciations given.

Comment: dictionaries have been checked, websites also, I just wanted to have an opinion from native speakers / experts, since I am neither. Do you say it like the dictionary?

Comment: You can't go wrong with the spelling pronunciation. That's not to say that, in rapid speech, some people wouldn't make it sound more like 'am'.

Comment: you can hear very frequently: "am this" "am that", is this wrong?

Comment: I pronounce it like in the dictionary. Those speakers (perhaps in Texas) who monophthongise it to something like "a(a)m" would probably pronounce the emphatic "I am" as "a aam".  Anyway, there are two separate questions here: (1) what range of pronunciations does "I'm" have among different speakers in different regions and (2) what pronunciation should a learner use (I would advocate the standard one shown in dictionary transcriptions).

Comment: yes, I have heard that in some south US movies and it can be quite likeable also, since it matches other intonations of that English. My question though is about correctness, since I have heard this "am's" coming from non mother tongue speakers from diverse locations, I am wondering if maybe - there is a second accepted rule, or something that supersedes even the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

In American English, the subject pronoun ***I*** is usually contracted, and reduced.

In particular, its contraction with present-tense *be* (which is very common because *be* is required for the Passive construction, for the Progressive construction, and for predicate nouns and adjectives) is pronounced /aym/ when said alone, but almost always the /y/ is dropped, leaving only /a:m/ as the normal form.

The /a:/ is a bit longer than usual, but since English doesn't have phonemic vowel length, that's hard to notice. Furthermore, when speaking at normal speech rate, the /m/ of /aym/ -> /a:m/ also gets reduced, leaving only a nasalized /ã/ as the pronunciation.

Thus,

- *I am going to leave tomorrow.*

can be pronounced

- /'aymgənə'livtə'maro/, or
- /'a:mgənə'livtə'marə/, or
- /'ãŋgənə'livtə'marə/, or
- /'amənə'livtə'marə/, or many other combinations.

Comment: will I find those contracted I forms in any american english dictionary?

Comment: Probably not. American English dictionaries don't report actual pronunciations, because Americans are not taught anything about phonetics or English pronunciation.